# Store and show emojis

Tags: php, mysql, swift

I use a TextView to user type a comment, I store it on data base and show on a tableview or label to user. But when the user type a emoji on middle of string, the emojis is stored like a hexa, how to convert this emojis again when I add on label or tableview?

Or I dont need to change anything on my swift code and I need to change my database to store emojis? Or my API PHP?

Comment: 1. What kind of database are you referring to? CoreData? Web server? 2. How are you saving the data?

Comment: What does "hexa" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection to MySQL must specify utf8mb4.

Your column/table must be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4.